# How to discover azure devops pull requests in jenkins Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to create `Multibranch Pipeline` for my git repository that located on `azure devops`.
I can discover & trigger changes on `branches` and `tags`, but unfortunately I can't discover new pull requests.

I want to avoid from working with the [tfs-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin), apperantly `azure` abandoned this plugin and you need to install it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897029/has-the-tfs-plugin-for-jenkins-been-removed) for god sake. But even if I'm trying to work with this plugin, I can't discover PRs. I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496426/4875299) which not helped.

So I moved to the [git-scm](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin) plugin, and I have tried to add `Discover other refs` with the following configuration:

```
Discover: pull/*/merge
Name mapping: origin/pull/@{1}/merge
```

[image]

Well, some how this helped me to discover new PRs on the branches list (fine by me), but it didn't work as expected, especially on `checkout scm` step which failed with the error `Could not determine exact tip revision of pull/74/merge` . I even open an [issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64719) on jenkins jira but they are not planning to help me with that.

so any idea on how can I use jenkins `Multibranch Pipeline` for discover new PRs from `azure devops` git repositories so on any new PR it will trigger the pipeline just like `github` plugin has?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the document using [TFS-Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin). It worked fine in my test jenkins pipeline. The new PR on azure devops repo will trigger jenkins pipepline. Below are my steps:

1, Install Tfs-plugin in Jenkins. [Set up credentials to azure devops](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#global-configuration).

2, Configure the [Source Code Management](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#git-1). Add below `Refspec` in the **Source Code Management** section

`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*`

[image]

3, [Create a service hook for Azure DevOps with Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops). See [Trigger builds when a pull request is created or updated in TFS/Azure DevOps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#trigger-builds-when-a-pull-request-is-created-or-updated-in-tfsazure-devops)

Note: Set the trigger to `Pull request merge commit created`

[image]

4, Create PR on azure devops, You will see jenkins build is triggered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the tfs-plugin will not discover PRs so the client will not be able to see list of PRs on jenkins and will not be able to rebuild a specific PR, instead it will trigger the job for any new PR which is not what I'm looking for. In addition, tfs-plugin is deprecated, not maintained and suffer from security issues

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "Discover other refs", you have to add also "Specify ref specs" with RefSpec value: `+ refs/pull/*/merge:refs/pull/*/merge`

The solution is available by this link: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10103