# Trigger Jenkins job due to a Azure git repo pull request

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops

I've read the documentation in [this page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md), and I can see that there's an option to "Trigger a build when a pull request is created". I did the following:

In Azure DevOps

1. Service Hooks -> Jenkins subscription -> Pull request merge attempted
2. Trigger generic build -> specify credentials and a specific build.

In Jenkins job

1. Create a Pipeline Job and check the "Poll SCM" checkbox

Now, whenever I issue a pull request, a build is indeed triggered, but my question is: how can I clone the Pull Request commit in order for the build to check if the pull request should be completed?

Another question if you will: I can see in my "Build Triggers" section those checkboxes:

- Build when a change is pushed to a TFS pull request
- Build when a change is pushed to TFS/Team Services

What is the use of these? since as far as I see, only the "Poll SCM" checkbox will cause a build to run whenever a new commit/pull request is created in the Git repository.

#### EDIT

Using a Freestyle job I can make this work by:

1. setting the refspecs in the SCM configuration as such:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*
```

2. setting the "Branches to track" to `**`, so that the `pull/*` branches will be tracked and built.

The question is how to make this work in Pipeline jobs.

Comment: Have you read this - [Create a service hook for Azure DevOps with Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: Yes I did, it only describes how to configure TFS to send notifications to Jenkins, no more than this.

Comment: @YoavKlein is it can helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518152/how-to-queue-jenkins-job-from-tfs-pull-request-with-merged-branch (you can try to trigger the jenkins from azure devops build instead of service hook)

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a lot of time messing with this, I found the following conclusions, which don't completely make sense to me:

### Trigger Generic Build vs Trigger Git Build

First, there's a different behavior inspected when using each of those options. Assuming the configuration of Jenkins is as follows:

*Pipeline Configuration*

- Pipeline script from SCM -> Git
- Configured certain repo and `feature` branch as "Branches to build"
- Poll SCM (For using "Trigger Git Build")

*Jenkinsfile*

- doesn't contains `skipDefaultCheckout()`
- `checkout(... branches: [[ name: '**' ]], userRemoteConfigs: [[refspec:"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*" ]])` (ignoring irrelevant configurations)

Now, create a new  pull request, the behaviors observed are: 
Using **Generic Build**:  the Default Checkout will checkout the `feature` branch. The `checkout` step may (and often does) checkout an old pull request commit, after stating `multiple candidate revisions`

Using **Trigger Git Build**: The default checkout **fails** since it doesn't know the commit object, since the refspec is not configured in the configuration page. After configuring this, the default checkout checks the latest pull-request commit.

#### Conclusion

So basically we're left with the following conclusion: 
In order for this to work, take the following steps:

**Azure DevOps Service-hooks** 
Configure a Jenkins service hook of type  "Pull request merge attempt", and set it to "Trigger Git Build"

**Pipeline Configuration Page**

- Set the `Poll SCM` option
- Configure a Git repository
- If you want to use the Default Checkout, configure the refspec under the *advanced* as follows:  `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*` and the `branches: [[name: '**']]`

**Jenkinsfile**

- If you're using the default checkout, you're set basically.
- If not, set the `skipDefaultCheckout` option, and use the `checkout` step with the `refspec` as written above:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '**']], , userRemoteConfigs: [[name: 'origin', refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*', url: '<git_url>']]]))
```

If someone has further explanation about these things, you're more then welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

To check out the Pull request commit in Jenkin Pipeline job. You can add the refspec in the checkout step like below:

```
 steps {
             
              checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
              extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch']],
              userRemoteConfigs: [[refspec:"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*",credentialsId: '<credentialsId>', url: "<git repo url>"]]])
              //
         }
```

Note: `credentialsId` comes from the **Jenkins**-->**Credentials**, where you add credentials for your azure devops repo. See [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md#global-configuration).

[image]

See below example result:

[image]

For `Poll SCM` in `Build Triggers` section. If you enabled `Poll SCM`, the jenkin server will polls the SCM on a fixed interval to check whether changes were made and builds the project if new commits were pushed.

Poll SCM Option is not recommended. Because it is an expensive operation for CVS. It is usually used when the "push" triggers are not working(eg. repo are in local source control server)

> Note that this is going to be an expensive operation for CVS, as every polling requires Jenkins to scan the entire workspace and verify it with the server. Consider setting up a "push" trigger to avoid this overhead

Comment: Thanks. Please refer to the edit of the question

Comment: @YoavKlein You can reference to above updated example to set up the `checkout` step

Comment: @YoavKlein Hi Did you get a chance to check out above update? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Comment: Hi @Levi Lu-MSFT, I'm sorry I didn't get the chance to check this yet. Promise I'll respond once I will.